# UITextField's resignFirstResponder is not working neither working self.view.endEditing()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I'm facing a ridiculous problem for textField, I have two textfield, namely tfA and tfB, I have set delegates and all for those textfields, what i wanted is, if I click on tfA then it should print something, and it is printing and if I click tfB it should appear the keyboard, well it is working well too, but when I click again to tfA then it should print something and keyboard should dismiss according to the condition given there, But keyboard is not dismissing there also `self.view.endEditing(true)` is not working here . Code is given below with screen shot, what I'm doing wrong here?

**CODE: Swift 3**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tfA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfB: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tfA.delegate = self
        tfB.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == tfA{
            print("TFA Clicked")
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }else{
            tfB.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**Screenshots**

[image]

Comment: Remove `textField.resignFirstResponder()` and try. When you come back from tfB ,its keyboard is active. So `self.view.endEditing(true)` is enough to dismiss the keyboard active in the view.

Comment: If you don't want the tfA to be editable why dont you simply do `tfA.isEnabled = false`

Comment: @ron27 i tried but though not working.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I need an action for tfA, thats why i cant make it false.

Comment: Create a button with no title and same position & size of tfA.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR yes, that way i thought too, and it will work definitely, but don't want to pass this problem this way. I wanted to know the problem and where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check updated ans

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   if textField == tfA
   {
       tfaAction()
       return false
   }
   else
   {
       return true
   }
}
func tfaAction(){

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it is not working either, my problem is if you click on tfB keyboard will be shown and if you click on tfA keyboard should be dismissed.
Also if you click on tfA first then keyboard shouldn't be shown. but in this I need an action on clicking tfA.

Comment: Thank Hero @RajeshKumar R, worked for me in just 5 Seconds.

Answer (score 7):

Remove your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method, replace it with `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  if textField == tfA{
    print("TFA Clicked")
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
  }else{
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4   Only check please this `delegate` if its exist then its should `return true`

```
`func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {`


    //MARK:- Textfield Delegates //This is mandatory 
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }

    //MARK:- This Delegate is option  but if this is exist in your code then return type shoud be true 
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

run `textfield.resignFirstResponder()`

so everything will be like

```
textfield.resignFirstResponder()
self.view.endEditing(true)
```